# Save all plots already present in the panel of Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I've made different plots (more than a hundred) for a project and I haven't capture them on the way (yes it's bad , i know). Now, I need to save them all at once but without running again my script (which takes hours). Is there a way to do so within Rstudio ?

Edit: All the plot are already there and I don't want to run them again.

Comment: if you generated them already, you could just flip back in the `Plots` viewer and save

Comment: @mtoto, yes I already know that. But through hundred of plots , it will be fastiduous...

Comment: If you've created hundreds of plots it would seem that you created them programmatically, therefore you can save them by [other methods](http://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder/)

Comment: Not easily. You don't have much control over plots produced that way anyway; it's better to use a device or `ggsave`.

Comment: @GabrielFair: probably worth mentioning your system details, as *I think* windows(), .SavedPlots  etc are OS dependent

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. :) Even more reason why this question should be revisited.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In RStudio, every session has a temporary directory that can be obtained using `tempdir()`. Inside that temporary directory, there is another directory that always starts with `"rs-graphics"` and contains all the plots saved as `".png"` files. Therefore, to get the list of `".png"` files you can do the following:

```
plots.dir.path <- list.files(tempdir(), pattern="rs-graphics", full.names = TRUE); 
plots.png.paths <- list.files(plots.dir.path, pattern=".png", full.names = TRUE)
```

Now, you can copy these files to your desired directory, as follows:

```
file.copy(from=plots.png.paths, to="path_to_your_dir")
```

---

**Additional feature:**

As you will notice, the `.png` file names are automatically generated (e.g., `0078cb77-02f2-4a16-bf02-0c5c6d8cc8d8.png`). So if you want to number the `.png` files according to their plotting order in RStudio, you may do so as follows:

```
plots.png.detials <- file.info(plots.png.paths)
plots.png.detials <- plots.png.detials[order(plots.png.detials$mtime),]
sorted.png.names <- gsub(plots.dir.path, "path_to_your_dir", row.names(plots.png.detials), fixed=TRUE)
numbered.png.names <- paste0("path_to_your_dir/", 1:length(sorted.png.names), ".png")

# Rename all the .png files as: 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, and so on.
file.rename(from=sorted.png.names, to=numbered.png.names)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: great answer! your first block can be replaced by `plots.dir.path  <- list.files(tempdir(), pattern="rs-graphics", full.names = TRUE); plots.png.paths <- list.files(plots.dir.path, pattern=".png", full.names = TRUE)`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, thanks for that. I have updated my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Nice - platform independent (and actually works) unlike previous answers

Comment: Great! Just found out that the PNG is created just upon actually viewing in RStudio, i.e. in my script plots created during a loop did not show up in the folder as PNG until after using the back(/forward) button (i.e. actually viewing) in the R studio graphics window.

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to change the temporary filenames with code right after the plotting before storing them this way? The reason to output a plot is often entertaining the option to save it.

Comment: Does not work on Mac OS X Mojave with APFS file system. Although it should support nanosecond resolution, it does not. I tried `date -r filename "+%s/%N"`, but it appears that the nanoseconds are not recorded.

Comment: Is there a version of this that works with plots output inline of an .Rmd file? That's how I do most my plotting, and when I looked in `list.files(tempdir(), pattern="rs-graphics")` there are no files at all, so i assume that unless they're printed to the plots pane they don't appear there

Answer (score 5):

Although this discussion has been inactive for a while, there are some persons, like myself, who still come across the same problem, and the other solutions don't really seem to even get what the actual question is.

So, hands on. Your plot history gets saved in a variable called `.SavedPlots`. You can either access it directly, assign it to another variable in code or do the latter from the plots window.

```
# ph for plot history
ph <- .SavedPlots
```

In R 3.4.2, I could index `ph` to reproduce the corresponding plot in a device. What follows is rather straightforward:

1. Open a new device (png, jpeg, pdf...).
2. Reproduce your plot `ph[index_of_plot_in_history]`.
3. Close the device (or keep plotting if it is a pdf with multiple pages).

Example:

```
for(i in 1:lastplot) {
    png('plotname.png')
    print(ph[i])
    dev.off()
}
```

**Note:** Sometimes this doesn't happen because of poor programming. For instance, I was using the MICE package to impute many datasets with a large number of variables, and plotting as shown in section 4.3 of [this paper](http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/publications/mice%20in%20r%20-%20draft.pdf). Problem was, that only three variables per plot were displayed, and if I used a png device in my code, only the last plot of each dataset would be saved. However, if the plots were printed to a window, all the plots of each dataset would be recorded.

Comment: I got `Error: object '.SavedPlots' not found`, though `.SavedPlots` is referenced in `?grDevices::windows`

Comment: Could you provide more context to your problem?

Comment: If on a fresh session I run `plot(1:10);.SavedPlots)`, I get the error mentioned above, so it doesn't seem like my plotting history is saved in this variable. Using R 3.3.1 on Windows.

Comment: It looks like this only works if you've enabled recording plots _before_ you started plotting. As far as I can see, you can do that manually when opening a window with `windows(..., record=TRUE)`, or by setting `windows.options(record=TRUE)`, possibly in a startup-script such as .Rprofile (and this needs to be run before a graphics device is opened, so more difficult in RStudio)

Answer (score 1):

If your plots are 3d, you can take a snapshot of all your plots and save them as a .png file format.

```
snapshot3d(filename = '../Plots/SnapshotPlots.png', fmt = 'png')
```

Or else, the best way is to create a multi-paneled plotting window using the `par(mfrow)` function. Try the following

```
plotsPath = "../Plots/allPlots.pdf"
pdf(file=plotsPath)  

    for (x in seq(1,100))   
    {   
      par(mfrow = c(2,1))
      p1=rnorm(x)  
      p2=rnorm(x)  
      plot(p1,p2)   
    } 
    dev.off()
```

You can also use `png`,  `bmp`, `tiff`, and `jpeg` functions instead of `pdf`. You can read their advantages and disadvantages and choose the one you think is good for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how Rstudio opens the device where the plot are drawn, but I guess it uses `dev.new()`. In that case one quick way to save all opened graphs is to loop through all the devices and write them using `dev.print`.

Something like :

```
lapply(dev.list(),function(d){dev.set(d);dev.print(pdf,file=file.path(folder,paste0("graph_",d,".pdf"))})
```

where `folder` is the path of the folder where you want to store your graph (could be for example `folder="~"` if you are in linux and want to store all your graph in your home folder).

Comment: I don't think this will work - I believe (though I stand to be corrected) that RStudio always writes to the device `RStudioGD`, replacing plots in the same device as it goes.

Comment: but in that case how is that possible that "All the plot are already there and I don't want to run them again" as says the authors? if they are drawn all in the same device you should see only one plot, as you say, Rstudio should be "replacing plots in the same device". I was assuming that the authors was using a kind of special function from Rstudio allowing him to plot each graph in a new window, something like that. But that's just a guess, the truth is I may be totally wrong.

Answer (score -2):

If you enter the following function all that will follow will be save in a document:

```
pdf("nameofthedocument.pdf")

plot(x~y)
plot(...


dev.off()
```

You can also use tiff(), jpg()... see ?pdf

Comment: It is or it was in 2016. What's is not working for you ?