# Storage of sessions plots in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I had a large process run which produced around 100 plots. However, my session has since stopped responding. Is there a means by which I can access these plots (e.g., if it is stored somewhere in a temp folder)?

Comment: This might be close to a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321775/save-all-plots-already-present-in-the-panel-of-rstudio

Comment: Since your session has frozen, you can't do `tempdir()` to find the temporary directory, but you might be able to do it from a new session to find where R temporary directories are stored, and then look for other ones in the same place.